# Random crash on access to my std::list<string> object

Tags: c++

I have been getting random crashes when trying to access my `std::list<string>` object and can't figure out why it happens.

I started out with an extern `vector<string>` object but I've created a class for accessing it now, use a list instead (not that it matters but probably more appropriate for what I need it for) and make use of critical section just to be sure, however it didn't help any.

When I was using a vector I had crashes when calling size().
Using critical section or not has the same effect.
I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you!
The code:

```
class CWordHandler
{
public:
 void AddWord(string text);
 void DeleteWord(unsigned index);
 string ReadWord(unsigned index);
 void ClearWords();
 unsigned GetSize();
```

private:
 list`<string>` WordContainer;
};
extern CWordHandler WordHandler;
// ----------------------------------
string CWordHandler::ReadWord(unsigned index)
{
 list`<string>`::iterator it = WordContainer.begin(); // crash
 advance(it, index);
 return index >= 0 && index <= WordContainer.size() ? *it : 0;
}

Comment: Are you sure it is the `begin()` that fails?  The call to `std::advance()` could definitely fail if `index` is greater than the `size()` of the container.

Comment: You using pointers in any part of your solution?

Comment: Oh you are right, the advance is not safe I did not notice that. It is at the first line that I break though.

Comment: None of the code you've shown should normally cause a crash. My guess (similar to @wheaties's implication) is that you've done something elsewhere that's trashing the heap -- but it's hard to guess what that would be.

Comment: @MNB that's why I asked what I did.  You're either linking to the wrong library version, using pointers somewhere that's trashing the heap, or a library you're using is trashing the heap.  Anyway you look at it, the heap is being trashed at some other place.

Comment: @Jerry - `advance` barfs if given an invalid range (tested locally to confirm)

Comment: @Steve: Yes, that's why I said "should normally". It's true that the standard simply says a precondition to using `++` is that the iterator is dereferencable, so (apparently) if you don't meet that, it's UB. It would be better to check that `index` is in range before calling `advance`, but my immediate guess is that this isn't the real source of the problem.

Comment: @Jerry - I'm concerned about that 0 return value in the error path.  MSDN says specifically that the C-string used to init `string` should not be NULL.  Am I missing something and 0 maps to a different constructor than `basic_string::basic_string(const char *)`?

Comment: @Steve: that probably is a much bigger concern. As far as I can see, that's the only ctor it could map to, and the standard has the same requirement, making it UB. OTOH, I'd be a bit surprised to get random crashes, at least on a modern OS. I'd expect it to act consistently (though I guess if he's only passing too large an index sometimes, that could give inconsistent crashes).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys I appreciate it, I haven't found out why it crashes, I am using the code in a DLL for program that's not mine. I did fix the index range and return 0 issues but I get the same. What might I be doing that would be corrupting the heap?

Answer (score 1):

Don't see how `begin()` can really crash, unless the `list` is hopelessly messed up on entry to this code.

Your error check needs to happen before you call `advance`, which will malfunction if given a range that is invalid.

```
list<string>::iterator it = WordContainer.begin(); // crash
if (index >= 0 && index <= WordContainer.size())
{
  advance(it, index);
  return *it;
} 
return 0;
```

The wisdom of returning a `string` constructed from 0 on error seems questionable to me.  Perhaps a `bool` return and a `string&` parameter would be preferable.

Docs for [advance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sf5ab5y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) say:

> The range advanced through must be
>   nonsingular, where the iterators must
>   be dereferenceable or past the end.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the issue with advance, I'll try to debug it and post more info here when I can. It just happens so random but like I said when I was using a vector instead the violation happened at the call to size() always.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
string CWordHandler::ReadWord(unsigned index)
{
 if (index >= WordContainer.size()) return 0;
 list<string>::iterator it = WordContainer.begin();
 advance(it, index);
 return *it;
}
```

<strike>Sorry for the format.</strike>